# Persisting a GWT Visualization API DataTable

Tags: java, database, gwt, persistence, visualization

What's the correct way to go about persisting a GWT Visualization API DataTable?

Should I find a way to serialize the DataTable object or should I write the table cell by cell to a relational database?

I'm trying to build a RIA using the GWT-MVP pattern described here http://blog.hivedevelopment.co.uk/2009/08/google-web-toolkit-gwt-mvp-example.html.

Edit: What about using JSON? Is there anyway I can get the DataTable as JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone else had the same question and answered it himself. [gwt-visulation-api-datatable-serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033081/gwt-visulation-api-datatable-serialization)

Your basic options then are:
Store cell by cell or use some ORM on the server side to map your datatable to the DB.